# Laravel Eloquent ORM relationship naming conventions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When defining an inverse relation in Eloquent, do you have to name your dynamic property the same as your related model?

```
class Book extends Eloquent {

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Author');
    }

}

$books = Book::all()
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->author->firstname;
}
```

In the above example, do I have to call this method *author* or can I name it something else? I tried to name it to something else (just out of curiosity) but it then returns null hence the errors "Trying to get property of non-object".

**EDIT:** I got it to work by passing the foreign key to belongsTo, like this:

class Book extends Eloquent {

```
    public function daauthor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Author', 'author_id');
    }

}

$book = Book::find(55);
dd($book->daauthor);
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: You can name it whatever you want :). What was the error and function name you tried?

Comment: if i change Book::author() to Book::daauthor() and call it like: $book->daauthor, i get null back.

Comment: I can rename my eloquent functions to whatever, tried it in my Laravel4 project. The function `BelongsTo()` does nothing with your function's name. Maybe you overlooked something in your code?

Comment: so in theory, changing author() to daauthor() in the Book class and then in the foreach loop using $book0>daauthor should return something? anything else i might be missing?

Comment: it turns out you have to pass in the name of the foreign key for it to work. did you have to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method **belongsTo** tries to determine the attribute which links to the *Author* model. To accomplish this Laravel uses the function name of the caller.

So in your code Laravel sees the **daauthor** function and tries to use the attribute **daauthor_id** in the **books** table to fully your request. As your books table does not have this attribute it fails.

By setting the $foreignKey on the method you can override the default behaviour:

```
public function daauthor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Author', 'author_id');
}
```

For more details check out the source code of *\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model*.