# Foreign Key relationship in eloquent not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have looked into this answer: [Laravel Eloquent ORM relationship naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750221/laravel-eloquent-orm-relationship-naming-conventions)

And this one too [Query foreign key data from Blade template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225197/query-foreign-key-data-from-blade-template)

But still not able to solve my problem.
I have two models: product and category, I want to display product data on my blade page along with its category [name ofcourse]. I know its possible to do this by adding it to the return data in my controller however I would like to do it leveraging Eloquent instead, however I receive errors.

Here is my code:

**product model**

```
protected $table = 'product_details';
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\category', 'category_id');
}
```

**category model**

```
protected $table = 'category';
public function product() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\product');
}
```

**ProductController**

```
public function index()
{
    $products = product::select('id', 'product_name', 'category_id', 'is_active', 'created_at', 'updated_at')->get();
    return view('admin/product/index', compact('products'));
}
```

**Index Blade Page**

```
{{ $product->category->category_name }}
```

***Tables***

**product_details**

```
id
product_name
catgory_id
```

**category**

```
id
category_name
```

Error I get:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: can you post the output of `dd($product->category)`? I suspect that is null possibly because category_id is empty or doesn't match the category table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Category is missing due to the value of `category_id` in product table is `null` or other `id` value which is absent in category table. You may check missing value in blade by:

```
{{ $product->category->category_name or 'Unknown Category' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using the wrong model name, by default, the model name is:

```
App\Foobar
```

Capitalize the "C" letter of the category

```
protected $table = 'product_details';
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
}
```

Capitalize the "P" letter of the product

```
protected $table = 'category';
public function product() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i see the it.

1. You are using **get()** to retrieve your products which will return an array so for you to access the category collection you must loop through each and every product to retreive it category. You can use **first()** if you want only one product.
2. I would advice you use eager loading to fetch your categories to prevent the **n+1** query problem. I think in a way it can also help to prevent the **Trying to get property of non-object**. The query will now be

   ```
   $products = product::with('category')->select('id', 'product_name', 'category_id', 'is_active', 'created_at', 'updated_at')->get();
   ```
3. It could also be that the product does not have a related category record which i don't think is possible if you are enforcing foreign key constraint. But if that's the case you can try the php7 ull Coalesce Operator.

   ```
   {{ $product->category->category_name ?? 'Not Available'}}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you wrote:

```
$products = product::select('id', 'product_name', 'category_id', 'is_active', 'created_at', 'updated_at')->get();
```

But in your blade file you're calling:

```
{{ $product->category->category_name }}
```

Did you write a **foreach loop** in your blade file? For example:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
    {{ $product->category->category_name }}
@endforeach
```

Otherwise you should call ->first instead of ->get and correct your typo. So the code on your **ProductController** would be:

```
public function index()
{
    $products = product::select('id', 'product_name', 'category_id', 'is_active', 'created_at', 'updated_at')->get();
    return view('admin/product/index', compact('products'));
}
```

While the code on your blade page would be:

```
{{ $product->category->category_name }}
```